# How to create a patched jar with maven (with the same group:artifact:version, but different classifier)?

Tags: maven, jar

I have some reasons to patch existing `jar` (the reasons are fairly irrelevant). I am trying to create a `jar` with the same `group:artifactid:version`, but with a different classifier. My attempted `pom.xml` is below.

Maven is upset about two things -- 1) It does not recognize `<classifier>` in project (the line with comment), and 2) It considers the reference the the bottom as circular (because the classifier portion is ignored, so this is a secondary error).

What would be a correct way to handle this situation?

(I removed plugins, but basically they are dependency copy and exec a shell script -- simple but bulky and irrelevant.)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project ...>
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

  <name>Patched TestNG</name>

  <groupId>org.testng</groupId>
  <artifactId>testng</artifactId>
  <version>6.13.1</version>
  <classifier>patched</classifier> <!-- this is the first offending line -->
  <packaging>jar</packaging>

  <build>...</build>
  <dependencies>
    <dependency> <!-- treated as a self-reference -->
      <groupId>org.testng</groupId>
      <artifactId>testng</artifactId>
      <version>6.13.1</version>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>
</project>
```

Errors:

> [ERROR]   The project org.testng:testng:6.13.1
>   (.../testng-patched/pom.xml) has 2 errors [ERROR]     Malformed POM
>   .../testng-patched/pom.xml: Unrecognised tag: 'classifier' (position:
>   START_TAG seen ...\n  ... @12:15)  @
>   .../testng-patched/pom.xml, line 12, column 15 -> [Help 2] [ERROR]
>   'dependencies.dependency org.testng:testng:6.13.1' for
>   org.testng:testng:6.13.1 is referencing itself. @ line 71, column 17

Comment: To create a patched jar, you usually just append the version number with something like `-patched`. Furthermore, why do you want to reference the jar itself in the dependencies? Why not just patch the source code?

Comment: I do not want / need to recompile anything. Also, classifier looks like more appropriate to mark variation of the library. For example, `guice` is provided in two variants: `4.0`, and `4.0:no_aop`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You ask for the correct way to handle the situation. In my humble opinion: Don't try to self-reference the jar, but go to the source code, make the changes you want to make and then build the artifact with the version number `6.13.1-patched`.

If you *really* want to add a jar with the same GAV, but different classifier, you need to work around Maven (which, in itself, is usually a sin). My best idea would be:

1. Delete the `<classifier>`. This tag does not exist.
2. Rename the `<artifactId>` to something different, like `dummy`.
3. Build the artifact with `clean package`.
4. Now use `deploy:deploy-file` with appropriate parameters to deploy the `dummy` artifact with the right GAV and classifier to the repository.

The last point is tricky and may not work. Note that you are trying to deploy an artifact without a POM (because the POM of the original artifact is already there), and this may or may not work.

Comment: _you need to work around Maven (which, in itself, is usually a sin)._


Thank you. I though, I am missing something in how-to. If this is against Maven philosophy,  I need to find a different workaround. Change of the version (as you suggested) worked in my case.



_Note that you are trying to deploy an artifact without a POM_



Thank you, this is a very important point.